# Analog to Digital Schemes - using different implementations?

Tags: microcontroller, adc, encoding

We all know the standard(at least traditional) ADC with output being the binary representation in base 2. However, there are a variety of other encoding schemes that are much better and less prone to errors.

For example, the Gray code is designed in such a way that each successive number differs from the previous by only a single bit. Such a encoding scheme means that if the signal to be encoded signal went from 7 to 8, the representation would differ only by a single bit in contrast to the traditional binary where `7 -> 8` has a 4bit change.

In traditional binary:

```
 7       8
0111 -> 1000
```

In Gray code:

```
 7       8
0100 -> 1100
```

How would you implement such an encoding scheme? Do microcontrollers have the ability to use different techniques or are they tied to the traditional method unless a specifialized units are purchased?

Comment: Delta-sigma doesn't play nice with Gray code.

Comment: How does using a gray code ADC make it less prone to errors? Analogue inputs don't conveniently change 1 LSB at a time so how can you justify it being less prone to errors? While you're thinking about that, what are the encoding schemes (you hint at) that are much better?

Comment: You need weighted code for ADC where each bit defines certain weight. Gray code is non-weighted code.

Comment: @Mandar: I think a serial-output ADC could easily be made to output gray code; since the most significant bit is generated first, simply xor each bit other than the first with the previous one.

Comment: @supercat I thought OP was interested to find out if such encoding can be part of conversion process, though I am not clear how that will provide error immunity. What you suggest is having as ADC and adding Bin-to-Gray converter in front of it. Maybe that is all OP is interested in.

Comment: @Mandar: If an ADC signal will have to cross a clock-synchronization boundary, using gray code will ensure that an error resulting from grabbing a reading just as it's changing will be limited to the difference between the two readings, though admittedly unless there's a serial-to-parallel converter before the clock boundary the issue would be moot with a serial ADC.  BTW, I think one could design an ADC which inherently read out in gray code, though getting good linearity specs would be harder than with a conventional one.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the most obvious reason why ADCs output straight binary is: because they output the code directly from the converter, and all popular ADCs 'naturally' output straight binary codes.

Successive approximation ADCs are the most popular kind. It works by comparing the stored input voltage to a voltage produced by an internal DAC (or R2R ladder). It starts by comparing the input voltage to half the full range: if it is higher than that voltage, it outputs a code '1', if it is lower - '0'. After that it splits the corresponding half of the voltage range into two again and does another comparison. It continues this cycle for the amount of bits desired. Obviously, this naturally produces a little endian binary output code, and always requires as many cycles as there are bits.

Sigma-delta converters are the other big type of popular ADC. They work by doing voltage-to-frequency conversion and subsequently counting the number of pulses in a given time span. Naturally, the less pulses you can count and the shorter the amount of time (in a clocked system), the worse your resolution. So this type of converter also naturally gives coarse values first and becoming more accurate as time progresses - again a prime example of little endian binary output.

In order to give out something like Gray code or other advantageous codes (for instance TMDS for maximum SNR) you would need to wait until a complete conversion occurs, then perform an operation to transform the code, and only then can the ADC release the output code. This means there is a significant time (latency) penalty to using another code.

The other elephant in the room is of course the fact that with extremely few exceptions, all architectures we use to process numbers use straight binary internally. In order to do anything with such values, you would need to convert them back again.

Of course, there is still a very valid point to be made for low-SNR transmission lines or in general for long-haul data transport to use optimized codes. However, ADCs almost never are used by themselves, they always have some kind of processing near the ADC. Moreover, there are literally no ADCs with integrated line drivers. Therefore, for these kinds of applications a code converter is almost always integrated in a line driver or physical interface chip (PHY), not in the ADC. Two great examples of this kind of conversion happening are panel drivers for LCDs (which all use LVDS to span a relatively long 10-50cm bit of wire at gigabits per second) and USB/Ethernet PHYs.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, gray code still is very much a binary representation it's that there is a *symbolic* mapping 1:1 from one space to another.  This can be done for many reasons, gray has minimized transitions.

The key that you are missing is that analog is called that because it is an analogue of the real world.  30 PSI maps to 3.0 Volts  0 PSI maps to 0.0 V continuously(for example) so your symbol's external representation need map to that, Internally it can be anything.  BUt BCD (Binary Coded Decimal) is an easier representation for our wee human brains..

It might also surprise you that there are ADC/DAC that DO use gray codes internally.  This is to ensure that there is no counting pattern imposed upon the output waveform.  the counter runs in gray code and the decoder maps from gray to a continuous space.  It also saves energy/power.